# Angular5 - ngx-translate Pharse value from json to lang.json

Tags: json, angular, ngx-translate

Is it possible to pharse data from a item.json to the lang.json? I tryed in this way but didnt work:

item.json

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "abilities.strength-plus, {{value: 5}}"
    }
]
```

lang.json (en)

```
{
    "abilities": {
        "strength-plus": "Strength +{{value}}"
    }
}
```

And tryed to output it in HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="list-title">Abilities</li>
    <li *ngFor="let abilitie of abilities">
        <div [innerHTML]="abilitie.name | translate"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The result is that he just output: `abilities.strength-plus, {{value: 5}}`

Any idea what im doing wrong? Without Data this way works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would work if you pulled out the object with the replace data in your `item.json` and then provided that as the data for ngx-translate.

item.json

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "abilities.strength-plus",
        "data": { "value": 5 }
    }
]
```

html template

```
<ul>
    <li class="list-title">Abilities</li>
    <li *ngFor="let abilitie of abilities">
        <div [innerHTML]="abilitie.name | translate:abilitie.data"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: ooops... My question was wrong... i need to parse the data from a third json file... I Edit my Post. plz take a look again.

Comment: You should have left this question the same and created a new one. It isn't beneficial for the internet to have a constantly moving target in a question

Comment: You are absolutly right, sorry for this. i revert the post and make a new one.